# Prolog First Steps: What is wrong about this code?

Tags: prolog

I just started learning Prolog and can not find my mistake. When I want to find sisters (and parents) of `jana` with `sister(jana)` Prolog just returns `true`.

```
child(hanna,sabine).
child(hanna,peter).
child(robert,sabine).
child(robert,peter).
child(peter,jana).
child(peter,christine).
child(claudia,jana).
child(claudia,christine).
child(claudia,jutta).
child(jana,jakob).

female(claudia).
female(jana).
female(christine).
female(jutta).
female(sabine).
female(hanna).

male(peter).
male(robert).
male(jakob).

sister(Person) :-
   female(Sister),
   male(Father),
   child(Father,Person),
   child(Father,Sister),
   female(Mother),
   child(Mother, Person),
   child(Mother, Sister).
```

Answer (score 2):

Such problems are common among beginners and are often easily solved by **using better predicate names**.

Importantly, note that a predicate defines a **relation** between things. Between *which* things? Ideally, this is reflected in the *name* of the predicate, denoting *what each argument stands for*.

For example, your code becomes *a lot* more readable if you write it as follows:

```
sister_person(Sister, Person) :-
   female(Sister),
   male(Father),
   parent_child(Father, Person),
   parent_child(Father, Sister),
   female(Mother),
   parent_child(Mother, Person),
   parent_child(Mother, Sister).
```

Note that I am using for example `parent_child/2` to make clear *which* argument is the parent, and *which* argument is the child.

So, it is clear that a predicate like `sister/1` can only state something about a *single* person, whereas you need a relation between *two* people. Hence, I have called it `sister_person/2`.

And so it works:

```
?- sister_person(jana, S).
S = jana ;
S = christine ;
false.
```

You can use **`dif/2`**, denoting *disequality* of terms, to state that "nobody is their own sister":

```
sister_person(Sister, Person) :-
   dif(Sister, Person),
   female(Sister),
   male(Father),
   parent_child(Father, Person),
   parent_child(Father, Sister),
   female(Mother),
   parent_child(Mother, Person),
   parent_child(Mother, Sister).
```

Now you get a single solution:

```
?- sister_person(jana, P).
P = christine ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is syntactically correct - returns true when `Person` fulfills the criteria e.g. has a female sibling, aka a *sister*.

```
sister(Person) :-
   female(Sister),
   male(Father),
   child(Father,Person),
   child(Father,Sister),
   female(Mother),
   child(Mother, Person),
   child(Mother, Sister).
```

You could use this to get all people who have a sister by doing this:

```
?- sister(X). 
X = jana ; 
X = christine ; 
X = jana ; 
X = christine ; 
X = sabine ; 
X = peter ; 
false.
```

As you can see, a person can have more than one sister, also, actually as the predicate doesn't check if Person ans Sister are the same or not - every girl is considered to be her own sister (see the answer by @mat to solve this). And also, which didn't occur to me, guys can have sisters too...

<sub>Result provided by @Lester, so this is the real output.</sub>

To get what you want, you need to define it this way:

```
sisterOf(Person, Sister) :-
   female(Sister),
   male(Father),
   child(Father,Person),
   child(Father,Sister),
   female(Mother),
   child(Mother, Person),
   child(Mother, Sister).
```

And run it like this:

```
?- sisterOf(jana,X).
X = jana ;
X = christine.
```

This seems weird, isn't it? But again, as we didn't check if Sister and Person are the same or not, every female is considered to be her own sister by the predicate.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I have learnt prolog ~10 years ago and never used it, so I'm definitely not up to date. Also, I don't have a Prolog engine anywhere near I could access, so the initial results were the result of the Prolog interpreter hosted in my brain, and updated the answer with the real results from the comments.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The first version returns `?- sister(X).
X = jana ;
X = christine ;
X = jana ;
X = christine ;
X = sabine ;
X = peter ;
false.`
The second version returns what you expected for the first version.
I still don't really get how this works...

Comment: Ah, yes... Guys can have sisters too...

The main thing to know is, Prolog finds **all solutions**. But the predicate you wrote had no "unbounded variable" to search for - it was just a simple question: "Does the entity 'jana' fulfill the 'sister' relation?" and the result is true. Same way, `sisterOf(jana,christine)` can be formulated as "Do entities 'jana' and 'christine' fulfill the relation 'sisterOf'?" and the result wold be true again. When used with an unbounded variable, e.g. X - the question becomes: "Hey, dude, get me all X values, where 'sisterOf' is true for 'jana' and X."

Comment: Only the presence of the second parameter... But in general,the solution of @mat is a lot better - he actually *knows* Prolog - I'm just an amateur in this field...